# Remove eventListener when another event fires does not work

Tags: javascript, events

I have two functions that create two different html structures for my app.
The thing is that i want to close thw info button event when the menu_div button is clicked and the opposite and i cant.
Please some help!!!!

```
const menu_div = document.createElement("button")
const info = document.createElement("button")



const Restaurant_info = () => {

    info.classList.add("info")
    document.body.appendChild(info)

    const info_h3 = document.createElement("div")
    info_h3.textContent = "INFO"
    info_h3.classList.add("info-h3",)
    info.appendChild(info_h3)
    return info
}


const menu = ()=>{
    menu_div.classList.add("menu-table")
    document.body.appendChild(menu_div)
    const h3 = document.createElement("div")
    h3.textContent = "MENU"
    h3.classList.add("h3")
    menu_div.appendChild(h3)

    return menu_div

}

document.body.append( header())


menu()
Restaurant_info()

info.addEventListener("click",location_info, {once:true, passive:true})
menu_div.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    info.removeEventListener("click", location_info, {passive:true})

    createMenu()
    
}, {once:true})
```

Comment: What if you remove the buttons entirely? If they are useless you dont longer want them in the screen

Comment: Thank you. I added two functions (one for each div that do the removal part and it worked) It was also my first wuestion ever in this site and i wanted to see how everything works. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I understood the correct meaning. But it's my solution, you can try.
I use "this" to judge the parent node.

```js
function fn(){
    if(this===info){ // do your things
        menu_div.removeEventListener('click',fn,{passive:true});
    }
    else{ // do your things
        info.removeEventListener('click',fn,{passive:true});
    }
}

info.addEventListener("click",fn, {once:true, passive:true})
menu_div.addEventListener("click",fn, {once:true, passive:true})
```

Comment: emm, to remove the other buttom is a good solution too

Comment: Thank you. I added two functions (one for each div that do the removal part and it worked) It was also my first wuestion ever in this site and i wanted to see how everything works. Thanks again